# how to handle click event on each cell of a table layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

I have a table layout which is as simple as [this one](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/grid.html#example).

What I need is to allowed end user to click each cell of the table, and do something on each cell.

But, it seems android **table layout** only support **row** based on click event, no **cell** based on click event. How to get rid of this?

Answer (score 6):

You need to handle the click events using `android:clickable="true"` and `android:onClick="clickHandlerCell"` in your XML layout definition file, in my case in a LinearLayout.

To identify wich cell was clicked you could tag the view of each cell using `view.setTag(uniqueID)` when you create it. In clickHandlerCell function use `view.getTag()` to get the identity of your cell.

Comment: If i use `view.getTag()` inside the clickHanderCell function, it just returns me the Tag of the Table not the cell. How do i get the tag of the cell?

Comment: @Oli, no, it returns a cell tag. When you create a TextView inside a TableRow, you may write: `textView.setTag(10)`. Then you create a listener: `textView.setOnClickListener(...); `. Inside it you can receive that 10 with `int i = (int) v.getTag()`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code for click in particular Table Row :

```
TableLayout contact_table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.contact_table);
final View row=contact_table.getChildAt(i);
row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        row_id=contact_table.indexOfChild(row);
    }
});
```

Comment: That row_id  doesn't help the OP determine which cell on that row was clicked.