# how to select table row items in table layout in android?

Tags: android, uitableview, calendar

I want to select a date range in the calendar by dragging across the table row. If anyone has any idea, please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can still start from this project : [Android Calendar View](https://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/)

Then add a setOnLongClickListener on the component.

With this listener, you should have the first day and also the last day. So you should be able to change dates appearence  between these.

Comment: i want to change date appearence by drag dates,please post code

Answer (score 0):

You should check this question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7147829/669647),using `android:clickable="true"` and `android:onClick="clickHandlerCell"`,then you can color the chosen in the `clickHandlerCell` method.